# My SQL server installation : 3306 port showing warning and not enable next button

Tags: mysql, installation, tcp

I tried to installed `mysql-installer-community-5.6.23.0.msi` on windows 8.1 OS. Every steps i followed for installation. But after installation in configuration settings i got problem to go ahead.

Actually i selected config type : Development Machine and in connectivity TCP/IP port was already there by default and its showing warning icon near to `3306 port number`. Due to this warning icon i am not able to press next button.

Please suggest me how can i enable 3306 port for installation MY SQL sever.

I am new for mysql and server side coding. I just started from the manual and i already had project which run localhost and 3306 port so I want this port to be configure in my installation process.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please read [the tag wiki for sql-server](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed issue by to take reference of this link.

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-open-a-port-in-the-windows-7-firewall.html

Answer (score 0):

An older instance of MySQL is still running and listening to the port 3306. You need to end this process manually, even if you did uninstall MySQL before.

To do this, go to "Windows Task Manager, click on the "Processes" tab, search for the "mysqld" process in the list, right click and select "End Process" from the menu.

Go back to the MySQL Installer window, retype 3306 in the text box, the warning symbol should disappear now.